# Unzipping from a shared smb folder golang

Tags: go, unzip, smb, shared-directory

I'm using the code below to iterate through a folder (unzipping `.zip` files locally, performing actions on them etc).

```
func extractZipWithPassword(localPath string, pathToServer string) {
    filepath.Walk(localPath, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        extension := filepath.Ext(path)
        fileName := filepath.Base(path)
        if extension == ".zip" {
            zip_password := "password"
            outDirZIP := filepath.Dir(path) + "/" + strings.TrimSuffix(fileName, extension)
            os.Mkdir(outDirZIP, 0777)
            commandString := fmt.Sprintf(`unzip -P %s %s -d %s`, zip_password, path, outDirZIP)
            commandSlice := strings.Fields(commandString)
            fmt.Println(commandString)
            c := exec.Command(commandSlice[0], commandSlice[1:]...)
            c.Run()
            zipCount++
            iterateThroughPE(outDirZIP)
            parsePKCS7(outDirZIP)
            splitter(start_string, end_string, outDirZIP)
            return nil
        } else {
            fmt.Println("")
            return nil
        }
    })
}
```

However now I need to extract archives from an SMB folder that requires login+password combination to access.
I tried using this lib [github.com/hirochachacha/go-smb2](https://github.com/hirochachacha/go-smb2) to access the shared folder, but to no success.
Is there a way to straight up unzip .zip files to a local folder of my choice with Go?
If there's not, what are my options?

**************************UPDATE**************************

Got the share mounted with go-smb2, not sure how to proceed next.

```
func listShares(path string) {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "ip:port")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    d := &smb2.Dialer{
        Initiator: &smb2.NTLMInitiator{
            User:     "user",
            Password: "pw",
        },
    }

    s, err := d.Dial(conn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer s.Logoff()

    names, err := s.ListSharenames()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, name := range names {
        fmt.Println(name)
    }
    fs, err := s.Mount("sharename")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer fs.Umount()
    
}
```

Comment: @gopher Thanks! Will do.
Also, updating the question, was able to mount a folder but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hirochachacha/go-smb2?utm_source=godoc#Share.ReadDir / https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hirochachacha/go-smb2?utm_source=godoc#Share.Open